# The application crashes when it does not find the parent

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a table with values:

```
  comment_id |  user_Id  | product_id | parent_id | reply_id | ... |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    164      |     7     |      40     |   null   |   null   | ... |
    165      |     7     |      40     |   164    |   164    | ... |        
    166      |     7     |      40     |   164    |   164    | ... | 
    167      |     20    |      40     |   164    |   164    | ... |        
    168      |     20    |      40     |   164    |   164    | ... |        
    169      |     20    |      40     |   164    |   164    | ... |    
    170      |     7     |      40     |   180    |   180    | ... |
```

I define which parent to treat the child comment:

```
    let comments = data_comments.rows;
    let comments_array = [];
    let tmp = {};
    for (let c of comments) {
        if (c.parent_id === null) {              
            comments_array.push(c);
            tmp[c.comment_id] = c;
            tmp[c.comment_id].nested_comments = [];
        } else {
            tmp[c.parent_id].nested_comments = tmp[c.parent_id].nested_comments || [];
            tmp[c.parent_id].nested_comments.push(c);
        }
    }
```

But my problem is that when the parent does not find the application fails with an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nested_comments' of undefined
```

Here 170 comments have no such parent, and because of this the application falls

How can you make sure that when there is no parent that is specified in the secondary commentary, the application does not fall?

Then I deleted the comment 170, because with it the application falls
The format in which I pass to the client:

```
"productDetails": {
        "product_id": 40,
        "product_name": "slippers",
        "product_description": "this slippers is good",
        "original_price": 7600,
        "sale_price": 4500,
        "discount": 41,
        "creating_date": "2019-02-28T04:43:04.000Z",
        "end_date": "2019-03-12T07:02:19.000Z",
        "date_period": "Mar 7 - Mar 12",
        "product_photos": [
            "https://..."
        ],
        "quantity_available": 150,
        "store_id": 9,
        "store_name": "Name Store",
        "contact_number": "123",
        "type_location": "SITY",
        "categorie": "LAPTOPS COMPUTERS",
        "starting_date": "2019-03-07T07:02:19.000Z",
        "likes": "0",
        "bookmarks": false,
        "is_liked": false,
        "comments": [
            {
                "comment_id": 164,
                "user_id": 7,
                "product_id": 40,
                "parent_id": null,
                "reply_id": null,
                "user_name": "Name Parent",
                "user_avatar": "https://...,
                "user_comment": "like product",
                "date_comment": 1551693424,
                "nested_comments": [
                    {
                        "comment_id": 169,
                        "user_id": 20,
                        "product_id": 40,
                        "parent_id": "164",
                        "reply_id": "164",
                        "user_name": "Name",
                        "user_avatar": "https://...",
                        "user_comment": "like product",
                        "date_comment": 1551693567
                    },
                    {
                        "comment_id": 168,
                        "user_id": 20,
                        "product_id": 40,
                        "parent_id": "164",
                        "reply_id": "164",
                        "user_name": "Name",
                        "user_avatar": "https://...",
                        "user_comment": "like product",
                        "date_comment": 1551693559
                    },
                    {
                        "comment_id": 167,
                        "user_id": 20,
                        "product_id": 40,
                        "parent_id": "164",
                        "reply_id": "164",
                        "user_name": "Name",
                        "user_avatar": "https://...",
                        "user_comment": "like product",
                        "date_comment": 1551693542
                    },
                    {
                        "comment_id": 166,
                        "user_id": 7,
                        "product_id": 40,
                        "parent_id": "164",
                        "reply_id": "164",
                        "user_name": "Name",
                        "user_avatar": "https://...",
                        "user_comment": "like product",
                        "date_comment": 1551693480
                    },
                    {
                        "comment_id": 165,
                        "user_id": 7,
                        "product_id": 40,
                        "parent_id": "164",
                        "reply_id": "164",
                        "user_name": "Name",
                        "user_avatar": "https://...",
                        "user_comment": "like product",
                        "date_comment": 1551693457
                    }
                ],
                "is_last_page": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: are nested_comments part of comments?

Comment: No, in this field I write down the child comments and pass in the format json

Comment: Your code seems to think that `c.comment_id` and `c.parent_id` match up some how, but I don't think they do.

Comment: can you share the format

Comment: Added as you asked

Comment: You need to check if the `tmp[c.parent_id]` exists in your `else` clause before trying to use it and if it doesn't, create it first.

Comment: @pmatsumura More? I did not quite understand you

Comment: So if `parent_id` is not null and do not exists, you want comment is parrent like cmt 164 or child of anything?

Comment: I want if the comment is not null and has a parent which is not, it simply does not include in the response to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my question comment, you are trying to access a property of an undefined variable. You can solve this by using two loops, which will populate `comments_array` correctly.

Try this (untested):

```
let comments = data_comments.rows;
let comments_array = [];
let tmp = {};

for (let c of comments) {
  tmp[c.comment_id] = c;
  c['nested_comments'] = [];
}

for (let c of comments) {
  if (c.parent_id !== null && tmp[c.parent_id] !== undefined) {
    tmp[c.parent_id]['nested_comments'].push(c);
  } else {
    comments_array.push(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How should I help you without the error message?

Comment: The error is the same `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nested_comments' of undefined`

Comment: Could you please paste the contents of `data_comments.rows` into [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)? I can then recreate a working example.

Comment: I did as you requested, in the example of izi comment 492 the whole application crumble 
 https://pastebin.com/j78N8LBn